# Gradle - java.exe finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: java, android, gradle

I couldn't solve the problem in any way. I am waiting for your help in this regard.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled = true
        applicationId "com.apaweb.track"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 14
        versionName "2.0.3"
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.+'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.tuenti.smsradar:library:1.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.async:androidasync:2.+'

}
```

I think that was the problem after updating the java.
`JDK 1.7`, `JDK 1.8` and `JDK 9` are installed in the system. I am using `JDK 1.7` now.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'. com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

[image: Environment Variables]

Comment: `multiDexEnabled true` .Remove `=` sign & use `compileSdkVersion 23`

Comment: NullPointerException: null, gave this error.

Comment: It would be somewhat more to the point to report what error messages were printed by `java`, rather than just state the redundant information that it 'exited with non-zero exit value'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. By upgrading Android studio and gradle versions.